# What is Something You Didn't Know

Tags: riddle

> What is something you didn't know, (A.K.A. You didn't know how he/she/it acts, like if he laughs at your jokes or if he likes minecraft, you know, stuff like that)
>
> but you knew he existed because he was living while you were living,
>
> and when you first knew him he was tinier than the eye can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it

> Your unborn Son

Because

Something you didn't know:

> You don't know how your son will react and what they will like and be like

Knew he existed

> Your son is alive when you are alive, growing and developing in the womb before being born.

First Knew Him

> You knew about his conception while he was just a egg and sperm